# Duplicate tags [provisional] [provisional-application]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[provisional](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provisional) [provisional-application](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provisional-application) are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to post this myself, but it appears this is already an open issue.

A number of questions are tagged with both, and there seems to be no clear distinction between the two. The descriptions for both of them are basically the same too.

I would propose that they both be merged into [provisional-application](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/provisional-application). "Provisional" alone may be a little vague, as at first blush it could refer to provisional rights or something.

Comment: I agree, they should be merged.

Comment: You should be able to suggest the synonym: >Users with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2. // Click on the tag and then on synonyms ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally had enough rep on the tag to add it myself ;)

https://patents.stackexchange.com/tags/provisional-application/synonyms

Now let the democracy begin, upvote, downvote, votevote! (On the tag, see link above)